# Grails JSON/XML generation fails

Tags: xml, json, grails, groovy

I have some code in my Controller that's throwing some unknown exceptions to me, can someone give me a hint of what is going on? see the code below:

```
class FooController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]


    def xmlList = {
        render Foo.list() as XML
    }

    def jsonList = {
        render Foo.list() as JSON
    }
//...
}
```

when I try to generate the JSON in the middle of it(the strangest part of it...) I get the following stacktrace:

```
[http-8080-2] [tenant 122] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /project/foo/jsonList
Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONException: Misplaced key.
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:161)
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:198)
at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:133)
at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:149)
at com.foo.FooController$_closure2.doCall(FooController.groovy:18)
at com.foo.FooController$_closure2.doCall(FooController.groovy)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

when I try to generate the xml, I get the following error on the screen:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 68: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

and the following stacktrace:

```
[http-8080-2] [tenant 122] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /project/foo/xmlList
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at grails.converters.XML.getElementName(XML.java:130)
at grails.converters.XML.convertAnother(XML.java:173)
at grails.converters.XML.convertAnother(XML.java:173)
at grails.converters.XML.convertAnother(XML.java:173)
at grails.converters.XML.convertAnother(XML.java:173)
at grails.converters.XML.convertAnother(XML.java:173)
at grails.converters.XML.convertAnother(XML.java:173)
at grails.converters.XML.convertAnother(XML.java:173)
at grails.converters.XML.convertAnother(XML.java:173)
at grails.converters.XML.render(XML.java:113)
at grails.converters.XML.render(XML.java:256)
at com.foo.FooController$_closure1.doCall(FooController.groovy:14)
at com.foo.FooController$_closure1.doCall(FooController.groovy)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

here is my Foo.groovy:

```
@MultiTenant
class Foo {

    String name
    String description
    List modules = new ArrayList();

    static belongsTo = [something : Something]
    static hasMany = [anything : Anything]

    static mapping = {
        table 'foo'
        version false // version is set to false, because this isn't available by     default for legacy databases
        id generator:'identity', column:'id'
        sort "name"
        description sqlType: "text"
        tenantId column:'tenant_id'
    }

    static constraints = {
        something(blank:false)
        name(size:1..100, blank:false, unique:['tenantId','project'])
        description()
    }



    @Override
    String toString() {
        return name
    }
}
```

Grails version -> 1.3.7
I'm new to grails, forgive me if I'm asking something newbieish, but I'm in real trouble here...

Comment: Can you post the Foo damain class and the version of Grails you are using?

Comment: there is also some code to jasper that I abstracted from here... I think thats not the real problem...

Answer (score 0):

I can't try your code at the moment so I try to suggest you a workaround:

```
def jsonList = {
        def foos = Foo.list()
        render(contentType:"text/json") {
            foos {
                 for(f in foos) {
                     foo(name: f.name, description: f.description)
                 }
            }   
       }
}
```

And the same for your xmlList controller method.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.call() is applicable for argument types:

Comment: What does "List modules = new ArrayList();" represent? can you try to comment it out for a test?

Comment: It looks like it's a relation with no other domain class. Let me know if commenting it out solve the issue with the JSON/XML conversion.

Comment: The problem is in the ArrayList as your stacktrace says. It's just a test.

Comment: actually module is a domain class... that has 3 attributes and some relationships

Comment: I don't want to make this thread too long. Your domain class definition doesn't look correct, the List modules doesn't mean anything for Grails so you should remove that and use the proper syntax for one-to-many relationship mappings. Maybe this could be the cause of your issue in the XML/JSON conversion.

Comment: ok, ill check it out... my biggest problem is that this code isnt mine, and I dont know it deeply...

Answer (score 0):

This is the work around that I am using.

```
def foos = Foos.findAll()
def array = []
for (Foo acc : foos) {
    def data = new Foo(id: acc.id,  bar : acc.bar)
    array << data
}
render array as JSON
```